# Java8 streams sequential and parallel execution produce different results?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Running the following stream example in Java8:

```
    System.out.println(Stream
        .of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
        .reduce("", (s1, s2) -> s1 + "/" + s2)
    );
```

yields:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

Which is - of course - no surprise.
Due to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html it shouldn't matter whether the stream is executed sequentially or parallel:

> Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, such as findAny(), whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel should not change the result of the computation.

AFAIK `reduce()` is deterministic and `(s1, s2) -> s1 + "/" + s2` is associative, so that adding `parallel()` should yield the same result:

```
    System.out.println(Stream
            .of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
            .parallel()
            .reduce("", (s1, s2) -> s1 + "/" + s2)
    );
```

However the result on my machine is:

```
/a//b//c//d//e//f
```

What's wrong here?

BTW: using (the preferred) `.collect(Collectors.joining("/"))` instead of `reduce(...)` yields the same result `a/b/c/d/e/f` for sequential and parallel execution.

JVM details:

```
java.specification.version: 1.8
java.version: 1.8.0_31
java.vm.version: 25.31-b07
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_31-b13
```

Comment: In fact it seems to [specifically state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that if your `BinaryOperator` is [Associative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) then this should work with parallel streams.

Comment: In addition to not following the rules for reduce, as other answerers have pointed out, there's an easier way to do what you're doing: `stream.collect(joining("/"))`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From reduce's documentation:

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t.

Which is not true in your case - "" and "a" creates "/a".

I have extracted the accumulator function and added a printout to show what happens:

```
BinaryOperator<String> accumulator = (s1, s2) -> {
    System.out.println("joining \"" + s1 + "\" and \"" + s2 + "\"");
    return s1 + "/" + s2;
};
System.out.println(Stream
                .of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
                .parallel()
                .reduce("", accumulator)
);
```

This is example output (it differs between runs):

```
joining "" and "d"
joining "" and "f"
joining "" and "b"
joining "" and "a"
joining "" and "c"
joining "" and "e"
joining "/b" and "/c"
joining "/e" and "/f"
joining "/a" and "/b//c"
joining "/d" and "/e//f"
joining "/a//b//c" and "/d//e//f"
/a//b//c//d//e//f
```

You can add an if statement to your function to handle empty string separately:

```
System.out.println(Stream
        .of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
        .parallel()
        .reduce((s1, s2) -> s1.isEmpty()? s2 : s1 + "/" + s2)
);
```

As Marko Topolnik noticed, checking `s2` is not required as accumulator doesn't have to be commutative function.

Comment: Nice! So using the `reduce` that does not use an identity also fixes the problem `.reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + "/" + s2)`.

Comment: A conditional expression would be preferred, IMHO: `(s1, s2) -> s1.isEmpty()? s2 : s2.isEmpty()? s1 : s1 + "/" + s2`

Comment: Also, since the accumulator function need not be commutative, you don't really need to check `s2` for empty. So, `(s1, s2) -> s1.isEmpty()? s2 : s1+"/"+s2` is enough.

Comment: Or he could use `stream.collect(Collectors.joining("/", "/", ""))`

Comment: @mk. That's not true. First step can be done in 3 threads in parallel creating a/b, c/d and e/f. Then we can join first two creating a/b/c/d and then join it with e/f creating a/b/c/d/e/f. I was thinking whether identity gives us any benefits, but I cannot find any good explanation - applying function with identity element is a redundant operation, it just yields the second element.

Comment: So the big question is, why doesn’t the implementation just delegate `reduce(identity, accumulator)` to `reduce(accumulator).orElse(identity)` internally as the requirement that “`accumulator.apply(identity, t)` is equal to `t`” implies that performing `whatever=accumulator.apply(identity, whatever)` in every evaluation thread is nonsense.

Comment: @Holger Maybe it's just because it wouldn't sit well with FP purists :)

Comment: Exactly this is the point: `a + 0 != a`. I didn't read the comment in the `reduce`documentation. +1

Answer (score 6):

To add to other answer,

You might want to use **Mutable reduction**, the doc specify that doing something like

```
String concatenated = strings.reduce("", String::concat)
```

Will give bad performance result.

> We would get the desired result, and it would even work in parallel.
>   However, we might not be happy about the performance! Such an
>   implementation would do a great deal of string copying, and the run
>   time would be O(n^2) in the number of characters. A more performant
>   approach would be to accumulate the results into a **StringBuilder**,
>   which is a mutable container for accumulating strings. We can use the
>   same technique to parallelize mutable reduction as we do with ordinary
>   reduction.

So you should use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who just started with lambdas and streams, it took quite some time to get to the "AHA" moment, until I really understood what is going on here. I'll rephrase this a bit to make a bit easier (at least how I wish it was really answered) for a stream newbie like me.

It's all under the reduce documentation that states:

**The identity value MUST be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t.**

We can easily prove that the way code is, the associativity is broken:

```
static private void isAssociative() {
     BinaryOperator<String> operator = (s1, s2) -> s1 + "/" + s2;
     String result = operator.apply("", "a");
     System.out.println(result); 
     System.out.println(result.equals("a")); 
}
```

An empty String concatenated with another String, should really produce the second String; which does not happen, thus accumulator (BinaryOperator) is NOT associative and thus the reduce method can not guarantee the same result in case of parallel invocation.

Comment: The associativity of the operator is not broken, the only problem is with the identity value. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity