# Stream works on sequential, but buggy in parallel mode

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Currently I am reading a [Java 8 Lambdas: Pragmatic Functional Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449370772) (very interesting and well written book, no adv.).

After chapter 6 there is an exercise:

> The code multiplies every number in a list together and multiplies the
>   result by
>   5. This works fine sequentially, but has a bug when running in parallel.

```
public static int multiplyThrough(List<Integer> linkedListOfNumbers) {
    return linkedListOfNumbers.parallelStream()
                       .reduce(5, (acc, x) -> x * acc);
}
```

And solution:

```
public static int multiplyThrough(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return 5 * numbers.parallelStream()
                      .reduce(1, (acc, x) -> x * acc);
}
```

I don't understand why first approach is buggy in parallel mode and there is no explanation in the book.

Please, explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724850/java8-streams-sequential-and-parallel-execution-produce-different-results

Comment: @ZouZou yes, just realized that this is close to question you pointed on. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t. The accumulator function must be an associative function.

This is clearly not the case in your first example:

5 * x is not equal to x.

The reason it doesn't give the same result in parallel mode is that, in this mode, the stream is splitted in chunks, and the reduction is applied for each chunk, and the results of each chunk are then reduced. So you end up multiplying by 5 several times, whereas in the sequential mode, the multiplication by 5 happens only once.

Comment: So the identity should be only 0 or 1 (0 * 0 equals 0 and 1 * 1 equals 1)?

Comment: identity * *any number* must equal to that number. Only 1 applies, 0 * 5 is not 5.

Comment: @user2138356 Note that in general, the "identity value" depends completely on the operation. For multiplication, this is one; for addition, this is zero. Other operations will vary as well.

Comment: You can completely eliminate this requirement by using the `reduce(acc).orElse(identity)` form. Now `identity` does not need to be an identity value for the `acc` function.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not following you there. multiplyThrough([2, 3]) would return 6 with your technique. Not 30.

Comment: I'm not commenting on OP's case. There he clearly needs to just multiply by 5 in the end. I was commenting more generally, you can avoid the need to write a function which has an identity value.