# Reduce from array of integers to double in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is my code:

```
// assuming HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap
double sum = hashmap.values().stream()
    .reduce(.0, (i, v) -> i + Math.pow(v,2) + 0.5 );
```

In this case reduce should take (Integer i) and (double v) and sum them and return this reduce as a double.

Instead I get this errors:

```
- The method reduce(Integer, BinaryOperator<Integer>) in the type Stream<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (double, (<no type> i, <no type> v) -> {})

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Integer
```

reduce,

However, this fixes:

```
// assuming HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap
double sum = hashmap.values().stream()
    .map((t)->(double)t)
    .reduce(.0, (i, v) -> i + Math.pow(v,2) + 0.5 );
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing so?

Comment: It's not clear to me what operation you're actually trying to implement, in terms of what you expect to be happening.  Could you write an implementation with a normal for-each to make that clearer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you just trying to sum the values of `v * v + 0.5`?

If so, the clearest solution is

```
double sum = 0;
for (int v : hashmap.values())
    sum += v * v + 0.5;
```

If you *must* use streams, the answer is

```
double sum = hashmap.values().stream().mapToDouble((v) -> v * v + 0.5).sum();
```

But it makes no sense trying to do this using `reduce()` because `0.0` is not an identity for the accumulator and the accumulator is not associative.

Comment: Well guessed. If that’s the intended operation, `hashmap.values().stream().mapToDouble(v->v*v).sum()+0.5*hashmap.size();` would be more efficient…

Answer (score 4):

A `BinaryOperator` must accept two arguments of the same type. However, you surely want to use

```
double sum = hashmap.values().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
  .reduce(.0, (i, v) -> i + Math.pow(v,2) + 0.5 );
```

to avoid unnecessary boxing conversions as [`Stream.mapToDouble(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) converts the `Stream` to a [`DoubleStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html). In contrast, calling `.map((t)->(double)t)` on a `Stream` will create `Double` instances out to the `Integer` instances.

---

But note that your use of `reduce` violates its contract. The first argument (you are using `0.` here) must be an identity value to the reduction function. “Identity value” means that for any value `v`, `apply(identity, v)` must result in `v` which is not the case here. Not meeting the identity contract [can lead to surprising behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28724850/2711488)