# Wrong result when using parallelStream().reduce()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to multiply all elements of a list together and then multiply that result by 5 using streams in Java 8. This is my code:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
int mul = numbers.stream().reduce(5, (acc, x) -> x * acc);
System.out.println(mul);
```

This gives me the correct result, 120. But if we change it to `parallelStream()` then it generates the wrong value. Why? Why does parallelization produce the wrong result in this case? And what is the fix?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28724850/2711488 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/32866581/2711488

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you're not respecting the [preconditions of the reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method:

> The identity value must be an identity for the accumulator function. This means that for all t, accumulator.apply(identity, t) is equal to t.

5 * t is not equal to t for all values of t.

You should use 1 as the identity, and multiply the result by 5.

Comment: But why it is producing correct result in case of iterative solution ?

Comment: Because the identity is only used once in that case, but is used several times in a parallel stream